# Generics - Clarification Required

Tags: c#, generics

When we declare (example) `List<T>` I can understand the declaration, but suppose I declare

```
IEnumerable<T<T1, T2>>
```

What did I actually declare?

1. Does it mean, `IEnumerable<T>` contains two generic types? (What is the way to use it?)
2. Can I have deep nested level like `Person<T<T2<T3<P1,P2>>>>`?

Simple example will really helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a class

```
public class Pair<T1, T2> { ... }
```

then you can declare a method

```
IEnumerable<Pair<int, string>> GetPairs();
```

i.e. a method that returns an enumerable of pairs where each pair consists of an int and a string.

Usage:

```
foreach (Pair<int, string> pair in GetPairs()) { ... }
```

You can also deeply nest these:

```
IEnumerable<Pair<int, Pair<string, string>>> GetPairs();
```

i.e. a method that returns an enumerable of pairs where each pair consists of an int and a pair of two strings.

This works with generics as well:

```
IEnumerable<Pair<T1, T2>> GetPairs<T1, T2>();
```

i.e. a method that returns an enumerable of pairs where each pair consists of a T1 and a T2.

But you cannot do this:

```
IEnumerable<T<T1, T2>> GetGenericPairs<T, T1, T2>();
```

Comment: Excellent buddy,Really helped me a lot. :) Thousand Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Unless you've actually *got* a generic type called `T`, that won't work. You need a real type there, e.g.

```
IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, int>>
```

which is a sequence of `Dictionary<string, int>` references.

But yes, you can nest generics a lot - and it becomes pretty unreadable:

```
List<Dictionary<List<IEnumerable<string>>, Dictionary<int, int>>> aargh = null;
```

Comment: are u jon skeet? why did you change the title to tony the pony?

Comment: Actually I am reading C# in depth in that you mentioned IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>> ,by reading that ,i raised this question.Thanks for clarification.

Comment: @Ankur: What do you mean, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

The above example will not compile.  But you can embed Generic types within one another with something like this:

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>>
```

Which would be an enumerable of an enumerable of ints (which would act as a jagged 2 dimensional array).

Answer (score 1):

(1) You declared an `IEnumerable` that enumerates objects of type `T<T1, T2>`. For example, `Hashtable<Int, String>`.

(2) Sure you can!